# Usage of cli command - sfdx force:source:convert

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx-cli, git, deployment-api, sourcecontrol

I used `force:source:retrieve` to retrieve the given list of components (classes, workflows etc) and committed the files to git. Now I want to deploy these components to higher environments like QA and Prod from Git.

`force:source:deploy` - I can't use this since it doesn't have the options like validate only or run local tests etc.. So I am planning to use `force:source:convert` to convert into mdapi format but even this does not have an option to convert a list of metadata, it converts all the source code in the root folder.

What are the options to convert given list of metadata (package.xml/list of files) to mdapi format and then deploy to sandbox/prod from git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.forceignore` file to specify the files which you want to exclude while converting to metadata format.

From [How to Exclude Source When Syncing or Converting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm) documentation:

> The `.forceignore` file excludes files when running the source commands: `force:source:convert`, `force:source:push`, `force:source:pull`, and `force:source:status`.

Let's say you have a DX project structure as below:

```
myproject/main/default/classes/MyFirstClass.cls
myproject/main/default/classes/MyFirstClass.cls-meta.xml
myproject/main/default/classes/MySecondClass.cls
myproject/main/default/classes/MySecondClass.cls-meta.xml
```

And that you want to exclude `MySecondClass.cls` from being converted into a metadata format. You can then include this file in the `.forceignore` file so that the output directory does not contain this entry. The entry in the `.forceignore` file should be then as below:

```
myproject/main/default/classes/MySecondClass.cls
myproject/main/default/classes/MySecondClass.cls-meta.xml
```

When you run the `force:source:convert`, the generated output metadata format directory will not contain `MySecondClass*` files or any entry in the generated `package.xml`.

Comment: Is there an option to only exclude during convert though? I have files I'd like to push/pull but just not convert e.g. permission sets

Comment: This also works for syncing between your local system and the scratch orgs as well. So as long as you have files specified in `.forceignore`, it will skip for any push/pull as well.

Comment: Right - but in some cases, I only want to exclude a file from convert - I DO want it when I push/pull - e.g. I want permission sets for my scratch orgs, but don't want them pushed to my package org. But it doesn't seem like there are two forceignore options?

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately there's no separate files for that purpose. You will need to manipulate the file accordingly based on the type of operation.

Comment: Created this idea to offer ability to differentiate:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EC1BQAW

Comment: You got my vote

Comment: @JayantDas so If I want to deploy a class, a custom field and workflow, then I have to list all the other files  in `.forceignore`. This will be very difficult since I have the entire metadata in the root folder

Comment: @ab0369 Unfortunately Yes, that's how you will be able to exclude the files not required to be part of metadata package. An alternate way would be to just copy only what is needed, in a separate folder and then execute the convert command from there. But in any case, you will need to manipulate things either this way or that way.